# F# and type inference: "int list" does not support "+"

Tags: f#, type-inference

Why does the following generate an error?

```
let mult a b = a * b
let sum a b = a + b
```

The second let generates a compile error:

> Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'int list' for a type inference variable. The type 'int list' does not support any operators named '+' Consider adding further type constraints

I don't get it. Why does it assume I'm inputting a list?

Full listing:

```
let sampleTimeSeries = 
  dict [
  "20110131", 1.5; 
  "20110228", 1.5;
  "20110331", 1.5; 
  "20110431", 1.5; 
  "20110531", 1.5; 
]
//  Recursive reduce function
//  func  : The function to apply
//  terminatingvalue : The terminating value
//  sequence : The list to apply the value on.
let rec reduce func sequence terminatingValue:int =
  match sequence with 
  | [] -> terminatingValue 
  | h::t -> func h (reduce func t terminatingValue)

let mult a b = a * b
let sum a b = a + b + 0
```

Once I added a 0 at the end of the sum function, it compiled correctly.

Comment: not an error for me of F# 2.0.0.0 - perhaps you have some earlier code causing an error?

Comment: The problem could likely be with code *below* this snippet, where `sum` is used.

Comment: Updated code still fine in both `fsi` and `fsc` - are you sure this is the code giving the error?

Comment: They are just declarations. Where do you actually use `sampleTimeSeries`, `reduce`, `mult` and `sum`? Post a complete example please.

Comment: I know they're just declarations. The declaration was giving the error as above. It seems that adding a 0 to the end of the list of elements to be added allowed the compiler to correctly infer the return type of int. Perhaps this wasn't clear.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Adding a 0 to the end of the declaration helped the compiler infer the return type of the `sum` function:

```
let mult a b = a * b 
let sum a b = a + b + 0
```

Comment: I don't think this is the real answer - there is some other underlying issue causing a problem here.  Whilst this works, it shouldn't be required and all the posted samples run fine without requiring the extra `0`