# Error: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'int * int' for a type inference variable

Tags: compiler-errors, f#

I have a simple formula for adding 2 numbers:

```
let add a b = a + b
let p = add(5,6)
```

which results in the following compiler error message:

Error: Type constraint mismatch when applying the default type 'int * int' for a type inference variable. The type '(int * int)' does not support any operators named '+' Consider adding further type constraints

The following works fine in the interactive window but I need it to work in my compiler as well:

```
let add ax bx = ax + bx;;
```

I looked at a similar question (The final answer scored -1):

[F# and type inference: "int list" does not support "+"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138368/f-and-type-inference-int-list-does-not-support)

Is the answer really to just add a "+ 0" to the end?

```
let add a b = a + b + 0
```

This sounds like a hack with an unnecessary processing overhead.

Comment: How do you call add function ? It seems that you call it passing a tuple `add (1, 2)` instead of `add 1 2`

Comment: Hi @Thomas, I've updated the code. It seems the issue comes in with the let p = add(5,6) statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a tuple to your `add` function in that line :

```
let p = add(5,6)
```

That's why it cannot work. In F# tuples are separated by `,` (comma) sign. Try to rewrite it like that to pass individual values instead of a tuple (separated by whitepsace)

```
let p = add 5 6
```